# Uploading a node.js app that uses socket.io to Bluemix results in 404 error

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ibm-cloud

I just created node js app using socket.io

For me in local it works fine, but when I uploaded it to bluemix, it gives me errors

Here is files that are working fine on localhost

app.js file

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.engine('html', require('swig').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
}); 

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log( 'A user disconnected' );
});
socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    console.log('Chat message ' + msg);
    var response = {
        'msg': msg,
        'address': socket.request.connection.remoteAddress
    };
    io.emit('chat message', JSON.stringify( response ));
}); 
});

http.listen(1234, '0.0.0.0', function(){
console.log('listening on *:1234');
});
```

and index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Socket.IO chat</title>
<style>
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
    body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
    form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
    form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
    form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
    #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
    #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
<input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
</form>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();
$('form').submit( function() {
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
});
socket.on('chat message', function( info ) {
    var response = JSON.parse( info );
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text( response.address + ': ' +      response.msg ) );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here are files on server

```
app.js file

/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------

// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require('express');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, function() {

// print a message when the server starts listening
console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.engine('html', require('swig').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html'); 
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                    console.log( 'A user disconnected' );
                        });
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
                        console.log('Chat message ' + msg);
                                var response = {
                                                'msg': msg,
                            'address':   socket.request.connection.remoteAddress
                        };
                                        io.emit('chat message',   JSON.stringify( response ));
                                            });
});
```

index.html file is same

and I get this error on my google chrome console

```
GET http://testingchat.mybluemix.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1440575370819-112 404 (Not Found)
```

I used codes from this [tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Who can help me ? 
Thank you

Comment: a 404 is very straightforward in that the file is not there, are you sure the socket server is running and you have the port forwarding configured on your host ? Im not sure about blumix specifics though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to your code you set socket.io listening on 1234 port.
On Bluemix runtime only ports 80, 443 and 9080 will be enabled for routing. Moreover runtimes engine will assign your local port dinamically and you have to read it from vcap services before setting socket.io using it.
Check on Bluemix documentation for how to do it.

About the 404 error, it is due to the request done to /socket.io/ path

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the socket.io module added to package.json in the dependencies?

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.6.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.4"
}
```

Also, try running the **cf logs** command from your terminal to see exactly what is going on when you run the app.

Comment: here is my packege.jsom file
{
    "name": "NodejsStarterApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "A sample nodejs app for Bluemix",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.12.x",
        "cfenv": "1.0.x",
        "swig": "1.x",
        "socket.io": "1.x",
        "socket.io-client": "1.x"
    },
    "repository": {},
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.12.x"
    }
}

Comment: on cf logs are not errors, all errors are on browser, I just cant understand why

Answer (score 0):

Here is my packege.json file

```
{
"name": "NodejsStarterApp",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "A sample nodejs app for Bluemix",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "express": "4.12.x",
    "cfenv": "1.0.x",
    "swig": "1.x",
    "socket.io": "1.x",
    "socket.io-client": "1.x"
},
"repository": {},
"engines": {
    "node": "0.12.x"
}
}
```

In log files are not errors
Errors appears only on browser